# Can anyone help me with this problem on exponential distribution please?

Tags: exponential-distribution

Ten years ago at a certain insurance company, the size of claims under homeowner insurance policies had an exponential distribution. Furthermore, 25% of claims were less than \$1000. Today, the size of claims still has an exponential distribution but, owing to inﬂation, every claim made today is twice the size of a similar claim made 10 years ago. Determine the probability that a claim made today is less than \$1000.

I tried my best but got an answer of 0.199 when the answer is actually 0.134

Answer (score 0):

So you are given that the size of claims 10 years ago follows some distribution $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. You also know that now all claims are twice of a similar claim 10 years ago, so if $Y$ is the size of claims now then $Y = 2X$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\Pr(Y < 1000)
&= \Pr(X < 500) \\
&= 1 - \Pr(X \geq 500) \\
&= 1 - e^{-500 \lambda} \\
&= 1 - \sqrt{e^{-1000 \lambda} } \\
&= 1 - \sqrt{\Pr(X \geq 1000)} \\
&= 1 - \sqrt{0.75} \\
&\approx 0.134
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you obtain that part
1- e^-500 lambda = 1- root of e^-1000 lambda

Comment: It's just the result that $a^{\frac{1}{2} b} = (a^b)^{1/2} = \sqrt{a^b}$